# How to remove foreign entity and then delete that entity from database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

In EF core 2.1 this worked just fine:

```
EntityEntry<Product> product = dbContext.Attach(new Product { productid = productID.Value, bildID = null });
product.Property(x => x.bildID).IsModified = true;
Document oldBild = new Document(oldBildID.Value);
dbContext.Attach(oldBild);
dbContext.Remove(oldBild);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But with EF core 3.0 this just dosn't work anymore, i get the foreign key constraint exception.
How am i supposed to do this now?
I would like to keep all of this in 1 transaction.

Comment: How are `Product` and `Document` related and are you sure you enter matching ID values?

Comment: Product has a **long? bildID** that points to the document thats assigned to it. Yes, quite sure that the IDs are matching because this is from a project i migrated to EF core core 3.0, and on EF core 2.1 it worked with no problems. I suspect that it wants me to **context.SaveChanges()** before unassigning bildID, but i want this to be in 1 transaction

Comment: You must have done something different with cascaded delete.